# 公園で母に… vs 公園で母を…

Tags: particles, particle-に, transitivity

Let me preface by saying that I am new to learning Japanese (about one month).

I came across this sentence and I’m confused about the particle に.

> 公園で母**に**会いました。

Why is に used here? If I use が or を, are those wrong or would they just emphasize different parts of the sentence?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/19820/why-is-the-%E3%81%AB-particle-used-in-this-sentence

Comment: Also related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/72206/5010